# setting upper bound on adjacent edges of vertices in igraph

Tags: r, igraph, vertices, edges, degrees

I am attempting to draw a complete graph using *igraph* of some arbitrary size. I then want to trim the number of adjacent edges each vertice can have. How can I do this?

As an example, If I have a complete graph of 20 vertices, each vertice will originally have 19 adjacent edges. Now I would like to trim those edges so that each vertice has at most 10 edges.

**EDIT**

Below is the current code I've written for this. It tends to form disconnected vertices and a small cluster of connected vertices.

```
library(igraph)
node_number = 20
g=erdos.renyi.game(node_number, 1)

testfun = function(g, maxVert, node_number){
  neighbor_nodes = NULL; delete_edge = NULL; delete_these = NULL
  total_nodes = 1:node_number

  for (i in 1:node_number){
    neighbor_nodes <- unlist(neighborhood(g, order = 1, nodes = total_nodes[i] ))
    neighbor_nodes[1] <- NA
    neighbor_nodes <- neighbor_nodes[!is.na(neighbor_nodes)]
    neighbor_nodes <- sample(neighbor_nodes, maxVert)

    delete_edge <- which(total_nodes%in%neighbor_nodes == FALSE)
    delete_edge <- which(delete_edge%in%total_nodes[i] == FALSE)

    for (j in 1:length(delete_edge)){
      if (isTRUE(edgeFinder(g, total_nodes[i], delete_edge[j]))){
        g = delete.edges(g, E(g, P=c(i, delete_edge[j])))
      }
    }
  }
  return(g)
}

edgeFinder = function(g, v1,v2){
    if (g[v1,v2] == 1){
     return(TRUE) 
    } else { return(FALSE) }
}

g2 = testfun(g, 10, node_number)
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. For example, are there priorities associated to the edges? Is it ok, if you reduce the edges to less than 10 for some vertices? Do you need an optimal solution? Or is a heuristic sufficient? You should also come up with an own initial idea on how to solve the problem. This would indicate that you did some research effort. Currently your question seems to be too broad.

Comment: @honk there are no priorities associated with the edges. It would be ideal if each vertice had a maximum number of adjacent edges you could set yourself. I did come up with my own solution but it is not working the way I want as it depletes the edges of most vertices while a few remain with edges. I will edit my post to share my current code.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this using the following approach.

```
library(igraph)     

SetEdge = rep(10, 20)
g=degree.sequence.game(SetEdge, method='vl')    
degree(g)
[1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

I'm now drawing a graph of 20 vertices with 10 adjacent edges. Simpler than my initial approach...